# Combining Optional.ofNullable() null check in java

Tags: java, option-type, null-check

I am doing a null check using `Optional.ofNullable()` for an API response where all the fields are optional (for lack of a better word), but we want to map the ones that are present, which may differ on each response payload.

```
Optional.ofNullable(details.getBadResponse()).map(property -> property.getResponseStatus()).ifPresent(property -> {
    responseData.setRawResponseCode(property.getResponseStatus());
});
Optional.ofNullable(details.getBadResponse()).map(property -> property.getErrorMessage()).ifPresent(property -> {
    responseData.setResponseMessage(property.getErrorMessage());
});
Optional.ofNullable(details.getBadResponse()).map(property -> property.getErrorReason()).ifPresent(property -> {
    responseData.setResponseCode(property.getErrorReason(), "serviceError");
});
Optional.ofNullable(details.getBadResponse()).map(property -> property.getId()).ifPresent(property -> {
    responseData.setRecordId(StringUtils.defaultString(property.getId(), StringUtils.EMPTY));
});
```

Is it possible to combine these statements into one `Optional.ofNullable` check on the details object (where `details` is the response object) to have the code be more clean?

Comment: Erm ... `Optional<...> badResponse = Optional.ofNullable(details.getBadResponse());`.  Ercetera.

Comment: Make it all statement != clean

Comment: In addition to @StephenC's suggestion, I'd add that the simplest thing here would just be `if (details.getBadResponse() != null) { var badResponse = details.getBadResponse(); ... }`. Not every nullable reference calls for `Optional`. Nulls are a way of life in Java; embrace them, and the code will often be cleaner.

Comment: Yea ... that's a better idea / approach.

Comment: This code makes no sense. You are calling methods (`getResponseStatus()`, `getErrorMessage()`, `getErrorReason()`, `getId()`), followed by calling exactly the same methods on the result of those methods. Maybe, you should stop your habit of calling every variable “`property`”, regardless of its actual purpose and type.

Comment: the bad response is the json response object, where the fields present can be null, or present. I want to avoid an NPE by mandating all the fields be present.

Comment: Don’t try to explain what was understood. Just try to compile the code that you have posted here.